Compute the sum of the previous group of rows and the sum of the current group of rows in SQL
I have a SQL table containing profit for a customer group, customer, project and year. I want to add the sum of the profit of the previous year for the current customer group and the sum of the profit of the current year for the current customer group to each row of the table.
For example, assuming I have this as my input data:



customer_group
customer
project
year
profit




A
A1
PA11
2018
2


A
A2
PA21
2019
47


A
A2
PA21
2019
12


A
A1
PA11
2020
70


B
B1
PB11
2018
0


B
B2
PB21
2020
5


B
B1
PB12
2021
23


C
C1
PC11
2017
1


C
C1
PC12
2017
4


C
C2
PC21
2018
10


C
C2
PC22
2018
6


C
C3
PC33
2020
11



I want the output to be this:



customer_group
customer
project
year
profit
total_profit_current_year
total_profit_last_year




A
A1
PA11
2018
2
2
null


A
A2
PA21
2019
47
59
2


A
A2
PA21
2019
12
59
2


A
A1
PA11
2020
70
70
59


B
B1
PB11
2018
0
0
null


B
B2
PB21
2020
5
5
null


B
B1
PB12
2021
23
23
5


C
C1
PC11
2017
1
5
null


C
C1
PC12
2017
4
5
null


C
C2
PC21
2018
10
16
5


C
C2
PC22
2018
6
16
5


C
C3
PC33
2020
11
11
null



I first tried to do this with window functions like lag, but the problem is that that does not look at the entire customer group in the previous year, just at the previous row for the previous year customer group, which has just part of the profit.
I also tried using a WITH clause to sum profits over customer groups and years, but left-joining this subquery 2 times with the original data gives very bad performance (the real data is pretty large, having > 1M rows).
Is there an efficient solution for this? Ideally I would need something behaving like a lag over a sum, but I'm not sure if this is possible.
Thanks in advance

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/XPxOqKNz

"I first tried to do this with window functions like lag", "I also tried using a WITH clause", so where is one of these tries???  We don't see it in your question.

Unfortunately, RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING which would have worked here is not supported in SQL Server (note RANGE not ROWS).
Assuming you are on SQL Server 2022 or Azure, you can use LAST_VALUE IGNORE NULLS.
WITH totals AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_group, year ORDER BY profit) AS rn,
      SUM(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_group, year) AS total_profit_current_year
    FROM inputdata
),
lastValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN
        LAG(total_profit_current_year) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_group ORDER BY year, profit)
      END AS prevTotal
    FROM totals
)
SELECT *,
  LAST_VALUE(prevTotal) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY customer_group ORDER BY year, profit) AS total_profit_last_year
FROM lastValues;

db<>fiddle
The steps are as follows:

Get the windowed SUM of the current year, and also the row-number indicating whether we are the first row in the group.
Use LAG to get the previous total, but only if we are the first row in the group.
Use LAST_VALUE ignoring nulls over that, to apply the previous total across the whole current partition.

The rows don't appear to have a good unique set of columns, so I've used profit as a uniquifier in the ORDER BYs. You should find a better column if possible.

Why would RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING not supported in SQL Server.  As far as I know, it works just fine.  1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING is not doing anything.

I think you are mixing up RANGE and ROWS https://dbfiddle.uk/4J5MV3X8 they are subtly different. ROWS just goes back/forwards however many rows you tell it. RANGE looks back/forwards in the ORDER BY a specified number of values. And ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING certainly does do something, it's the equivalent of LAG. It's RANGE that we want, in order to jump entire year values.

I don't think RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING would have worked, since that looks at the previous year available, so if we have profit for 2020 and 2018 and we want the profit for the previous year for 2020, it would give 2018's value instead of null for 2019

This solution doesn't work for that either, in fact no solution will unless you have a calendar table containing a list of years, which you then take and left-join your table to.

One of the options could be using Sum() Over() and Row_Number() Over() analytic functions like here:
WITH     --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( customer_group, customer, project, year, profit)  AS
     ( Select 'A',  'A1',   'PA11', 2018,   2      Union All
       Select 'A',  'A2',   'PA21', 2019,   47     Union All
       Select 'A',  'A2',   'PA21', 2019,   12     Union All
       Select 'A',  'A1',   'PA11', 2020,   70     Union All
       Select 'B',  'B1',   'PB11', 2018,   0      Union All
       Select 'B',  'B2',   'PB21', 2020,   5      Union All
       Select 'B',  'B1',   'PB12', 2021,   23     Union All
       Select 'C',  'C1',   'PC11', 2017,   1      Union All
       Select 'C',  'C1',   'PC12', 2017,   4      Union All
       Select 'C',  'C2',   'PC21', 2018,   10     Union All
       Select 'C',  'C2',   'PC22', 2018,   6      Union All
       Select 'C',  'C3',   'PC33', 2020,   11              )

--      S Q L :
SELECT t.customer_group, t.customer, t.project, t.year, t.profit,
       Sum(t.profit) Over(Partition By t.customer_group, t.year) as Total_profit_current_year,
       prev.Total_profit_previous_year
FROM   tbl t
LEFT JOIN (  Select  t.year, t.customer_group, t.customer, t.project, 
                     Sum(t.profit) Over(Partition By t.customer_group, t.year) as Total_profit_previous_year, 
                     Row_Number() Over(Partition By t.customer_group, t.year
                                       Order By  t.customer, t.project, t.profit) as rn
             From       tbl t 
          )  prev ON(prev.year = t.year - 1 And 
                     prev.customer_group = t.customer_group And
                     Coalesce(prev.rn, 1) = 1
                    )
ORDER BY  t.customer_group, t.year, t.customer, t.project

/*      R e s u l t :
customer_group  customer    project     year    profit  Total_profit_current_year   Total_profit_previous_year
--------------  --------    -------   ------  --------  -------------------------  ---------------------------
A               A1          PA11        2018         2                          2                         null
A               A2          PA21        2019        12                         59                            2
A               A2          PA21        2019        47                         59                            2
A               A1          PA11        2020        70                         70                           59
B               B1          PB11        2018         0                          0                         null
B               B2          PB21        2020         5                          5                         null
B               B1          PB12        2021        23                         23                            5
C               C1          PC11        2017         1                          5                         null  
C               C1          PC12        2017         4                          5                         null  
C               C2          PC21        2018        10                         16                            5  
C               C2          PC22        2018         6                         16                            5  
C               C3          PC33        2020        11                         11                         null     */

See the fiddle here.
